# Optimal apache configuration

Tags: apache, optimization, apache2, apache-config

I have the `pre_virtualhost_global.conf` with these settings (`worker MPM`):

```
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 10
MaxKeepAliveRequests 500 

ServerLimit 16
MaxClients 512
MinSpareThreads 96
MaxSpareThreads 512
ThreadLimit 64
ThreadsPerChild 64
ThreadStackSize 2097152
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
```

and the dayli munin graph:

[image]

In the peak the `server load` is about 1.2, I have 4 core of CPU.

Soon I expect a traffic about two times more than it is in the graph.

My first question is everything ok with my configuration to accept much more traffic?
Second: When the server creates new threads I experience about 25-50% higher load for about 2-3 minutes, I think because of memory realocation or something. It is possible to set the server to create threads to maximum, I mean in my case to be 1024 idle threads when the server has no traffic? I have to mention, I have enough memory to serve 1024 threads.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking with Worker MPM and prefork could help in less memory consumption but increasing the maximum thread requests and max keep live request could help serving more traffic. Try this below link for [Optimizing Apache for performance](http://www.hostocol.in/base/apache/optime-apache-for-better-performance-and-ram-usage/)